# Slots - Reel with a predefined symbol positions or make each symbol change independently on the others

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, random

I'm making a slot machine game and I need some advice on how to implement the spinning reels or how it's usually done. Right now, I'm thinking about two different approaches that would make sense - if you know any other way to implement this, please do share - and I don't know which one is better or the more common (if either of those is even right).

**Approach No.1** - Predefined Reels

In this approach, the symbols on the reels are predefined and fixed in place (akin to how it's done on the old-school mechanical slots) and the reels rotate like this.

[image: Approach No.1 Illustration]

**Approach No.2** - Random Symbols

Here all the symbols are randomly chosen on the go, just before the symbol appears in the view.

[image: Approach No.2 Illustration]

Which one of these approaches is the right way to go, if either. Are there any alternative solutions that are used normally?

Comment: Either of these approaches is valid, depending on how you want your game to play. If you want players to be able to learn the sequence on a reel and use that to anticipate when to pull the stop to get their chosen symbol, one method obviously supports that. If you don't want to support or imply that strategic play like that is supported, your alternative effectively takes it off the table. So, the question really boils down to: what playstyle do you want to encourage?

Comment: Hmmm, that's actually a really good way to think about it. Right now I have the second way implemented (mostly just because it was faster to get things running this way in Phaser), but considering I want to implement backwards spins as well, the first approach might be better for this kind of gameplay. Thank you! :)

Comment: If you've reasoned your way to a solution that works for you, please consider writing it up as an Answer below. It's absolutely OK to answer your own questions on this site.

Comment: I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else wants to answer and then I'll post my reasoning))

Comment: I thought you pulled the lever to _start_ turning the reels, not to _stop_ them. (So one does not have any control on the outcome.)

Comment: @Vaillancourt most slot machines actually let you do both.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on a couple of factors, and none of them are governed by technical ease of implementation.

You'll probably want to go with a predefined set of images

- if you want to advertise your game as "close to the real thing". Images are attached to reels and so the users should be able to figure the amount of images on a reel and the sequence.
- if you want to let the users try to stop the reel over precise images.

Whether you want to have the reel go in "reverse" after it has been going "forward" is irrelevant here, as you would simply store the generated pictograms and reuse them in the sequence it is stored.

Another thing to consider before deciding this is how you'll use your random number generation and how you'll decide how often you want your players to win.

Going with the "real" thing, you'll decide upfront the probability of each symbol to get picked, and it's going to be "relatively" easy to tune how often the player wins. However, if you decide to go ahead with "randomly selected" symbols, you'll have to come up with an algorithm that will let you tune what symbols are randomly selected.

So I suggest you figure out how you'll decide how the player wins, and how you want to market your game; that'll help you decide what approach you should use.